# Firebase client-side fan-out for data consistency

Tags: firebase

From the blow post below

[Firebase client-side fan-out for data consistency](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-10-07-how-to-keep-your-data-consistent.html)

Multi-path updates sound awesome. Does that work the same for Multi-path deletes?

**Use case**: I add a new post and it is fanned-out to many many followers. I decide to delete the post later on. Does the delete work the same? Do you have an example?

Comment: Not sure why this question got downvoted.. definitely a valid one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can delete many posts in a single operation, by setting the value for each key to null.

```
function deletePostFromFollowers(postId, followers) {
    var updates = {};
    followers.forEach(function(followerId) {
        updates['/users/'+followerId+'/posts/+'postId] = null
    });
    ref.update(updates);
}
deletePostFromFollowers('-K18713678adads', ['uid1', 'uid2']);
```

Comment: Thank you @Frank van Puffelen

Comment: this doesn't seem like it can scale, what happens if there are 1 million users for example? is it really efficient for our data to update values at 1 million locations?

Comment: @Wink I think it is pretty good. But you should make it with cloud functions on server side

Comment: btw, Frank, can u help me, please? What should i do with likes and comments count of post? Should I have likes/comments count in each post mention and update each post likes/comments count on each like/comment event? Or its better to have another node, like postscommentscount/postslikescount? Thanks you so much. And sorry, that I'm asking it here. But it is realy hard thing